# Simple web socket server, using nodeJS and "net"

Tags: node.js, websocket

Maybe someone have an example of a web-socket server using just nodejs "net" package, without "ws" lib or socket.io.
I tried to use net.createServer, but it seems i missing something, and i can't find any examples without the dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebSocket protocol [isn't trivial to implement](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

If you don't want to use `ws` (why not?), you can still use [its code](https://github.com/einaros/ws) to get an idea on how to implement the protocol.

Comment: about WS, i need to implement it on my own. I've already read the specification, but it's don't relay get it. And i'm looking for some simple implementation of this protocol to understand it

Comment: A non-trivial protocol probably doesn't have "some simple implementation".